# Propose a decreasing function bounded between $\frac{\log(M)}{M}$ and $\frac{1}{\log(M)}$

Tags: functions

Let $M\in \mathbb{N}$. Could you suggest (if any) some functions of $M$ that are

-bounded between $\frac{\log(M)}{M}$ and $\frac{1}{\log(M)}$ as $M\rightarrow \infty$

-decreasing as $M$ grows

Comment: I am confused as to why not take $1/\log M$ to begin with -- it does fit the bill.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take $\frac1{\sqrt M}$, which is the geometric mean of your functions.

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

$$f\left(M\right) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       1 & : M=1\\
       \frac{\frac{\log(M)}{M}+\frac{1}{\log(M)}}{2} & : \operatorname{else}
     \end{array}
   \right.\\$$